# How can I enable members to use the /function command

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want players in my Minecraft world (Bedrock Edition) to be able to use the function command without being given operator permissions. Is this possible through the use of behaviour packs or commands? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Does MCBE even have functions? I thought it had no datapacks. Anyway, I am pretty sure (without ever having played MCBE) there is no such permission system. MCJava has `/trigger`, but apparently not MCBE, according to the wiki. So you probably need to do custom triggers, like dropping a specific item, jumping five times, etc.

Comment: @FabianRöling [MCBE does have functions](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Function_(Bedrock_Edition)) using [add-ons](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Add-on). But you're right in that there is no command like `/trigger`.

Answer (score -1):

> So you probably need to do custom triggers, like dropping a specific item, jumping five times, etc.

You *could* run a function when a player drops a specific item, with a repeating and always active command block. The command would be

```
execute @e[type=item,name=<name of item in quotes>] ~~~ function <name of function>
```

- Replace `<name of item in quotes>` with the name of the item you want to detect the drop of in quotes.
- Replace `<name of function>` with the name of the function that you want to run.

Comment: That’s not gonna work. The `name` has to be set to the localized name, like “Diamond Sword”

Comment: @Penguin So how would I edit my answer so it *does* work?

Comment: @Pengiun would I say *`<Name of item in quotes>`*?

Comment: yes! Something like that.